# Paginating eager loading in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eager-loading

I'm trying to get products through categories and show products under categories. Also I need to add pagination for each category products. I have tried below solution and I got all the categories, but I'm getting products only for one category and other with empty products.

```
    $this->category->with(['products' => function ($query) {
        $query->paginate(3);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: You cannot paginate a relation... it makes no sense, as the "main" model here is `category`, how can you paginate the relation ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti How can I do this? .Do I have to get categories one by one?

Comment: You cannot paginate a related model, you can only paginate the main model, so, if you want to only get X amount of `products`, you will have to use `limit` as the answer down below but that is as much as you can do, you cannot paginate a related model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is paginate categories, but only categories with products. Read about `whereHas` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Sample code:

```
$this->category->with([
    'products' => function ($query) {
        $query->limit(3);
    }
])
->whereHas('products')
->paginate(10);
```

If you don't want to limit 3 products, then simply remove the closure from the `with` array.
If you know that you won't have too many categories, you can remove paginate at all (and therefore retrieve all categories in the  database, but only those with products).